# Making GetEnumerator ThreadSafe

Tags: c#, enumeration

Exactly how do enumerators work - I know that they build a state machine behind the scenes but if I call GetEnumerator twice will I get two different objects?

If I do something like this

```
  public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
  {
     yield return 1;
     yield return 2;
  }
```

Can I aquire a lock at the start of the method and is this lock held until the enumerator has returned null or until the enumerator is GC'd?

What happens if the caller resets the enumerator etc -

I guess my question is what is the best way to manage locking when dealing with an enumerator

Note: The client cannot be responsible for thread syncronisation - The class internally needs to be

And finally the example above is a simplification of the problem- The yield statements do a bit more then what I have shown :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C#: How can I make an IEnumerable<T> thread safe?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1605745/c-how-can-i-make-an-ienumerablet-thread-safe)

Answer (score 10):

Yes, each call to your `GetEnumerator()` method will create a different object (a new state machine).

You *can* acquire a lock within an iterator block, but be aware that none of the code in your method will be called until the caller calls `MoveNext()` for the first time.

In general, I would advise *against* holding a lock within an iterator block if at all possible. You don't know what the caller is going to do between calls to `MoveNext()`. So long as they dispose of the iterator at some point, the lock will be released eventually, but it still means you're at the mercy of the caller.

If you can give us more information about what you're trying to do, that would help. An alternative design which *might* be easier to get right would be:

```
public void DoSomething(Action<T> action)
{
    lock (...)
    {
        // Call action on each element in here
    }
}
```

Comment: I am making my own DataStructure which needs to be IEnumerable and also needs to be thread safe - I have safeguarded all the reads and writes but cant work out how to do thread locking for the enumerator

Comment: Can I just ask - If I put a lock on entry to the method above and release lock after all the yield return statements have completed will the lock be held for the duration of enumeration?  That might suffice.

Comment: @CycleMachine: You need to define what you mean by "thread safe" first. For example, if your data structure were immutable, you wouldn't need any locking... I'd be wary of a design which locked everything implicitly while you're iterating.

Answer (score 2):

As John already said it is difficult to give you a good answer. 
The obvious google search leads to: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/safe_enumerable.aspx

The idea behind this is to lock the IEnumerable instance on construction which has major drawbacks.

The next obvious thing is isolation where you create a copy of your structure and iterate over the copy. This is if naively implemented very memory consuming but it can be worth it if your data set is relatively small.

The best thing would be if your data is immutable then you have automatic thread safety but if you are bound to a collection which count does change you have a mutable data structure. If you could redesign your data structure into an immutable one you are done.

Since it is not a good idea to lock the data for a potentially long time you can implement strategies to achieve thread safety when you take advantage of you exact data structure and use case. If you for example change the data rarely and enumerate it frequently you could implement an optimistic enumerable which does read before start of the enumeration a write counter of your data structure and yields the results as usual. If a write happens in between you can throw an exception to signal the user of your enumerator to try again until he succeeds. This does work but delegates responsibility onto the caller of your enumerable that he needs retry the enumeration until it succeeds.